# Rendering checkboxes for table using jquery and ajax in a SPRING MVC and JSP environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am using `ajax` to retrieve data from the *database* and fill a `data table` on the front end. My code is working fine and the `<table>` is rendered correctly, however I want to have a `checkbox` in the first column. I tried couple of solutions but still fighting with this.

**My Table:**

```
<table id="importIssueTable">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Estimate in minutes</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**The ajax call**

```
$('#searchButton').click( function() {
        alert('in submit function');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getIssues',
            data: $("#importIssuesForm").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, result) {
                    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html()); //checkboxes here! 
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.thirdPartyId));
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.issueTitle));
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.originalEstimate));
                    $('#importIssueTable tr:last').after($tr);
                });            
            }
        });
    });
```

Without the `checkboxes` the *table* is rendered fine, but I would like to have a mechanism to select multiple elements from the `table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

****I think the below code will help you.****

```
 var str;
 $.each(data, function(index, result) {

     str +='<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="name[]"></td>'; 
     str +='<td>'+result.thirdPartyId+'</td>'; 
     str +='<td>'+result.issueTitle+'</td>'; 
     str +='<td>'+result.originalEstimate+'</td></tr>'; 
}); 

$('#importIssueTable').append(str);
```

and append the dynamic content at once not in every loop that will cause performance issue.

Comment: Great thanks. Changed the append operator from ".=" to "+=" and works fine.